# Adding a conditioned extra field to a query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables

TABLE 1 ( tournaments_data )

```
tournament_id | accound_id | data1 | data2
```

TABLE 2 ( tournaments_subscriptions )

```
tournament_id | account_id
```

Here, i have to read data of table 1 like this

```
SELECT data1,data2 from tournaments_data WHERE 1
```

adding an extra field to each row result, which has to be true if a specific account_id is subscribed to a specific tournament, and has to be false if the account_id is not subscribed. A account_id is subscribed to a tournament if we can find a row in the second table where accound_id is coupled to a specific tournament_id.
A practical example

```
tournament_id | account_id | data1 | data2
      1             1        data1a  data2a
      2             5        data1b  data2b

tournament_id | account_id
      1             1
```

Expected result

```
data1a data2a true
data1b data2b false
```

querying for account_id=1.
Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Wait... is `account_id` the same as `accound_id`, or is there a typo? If correct please elaborate.

Comment: sorry it is a typo, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed both columns are named `account_id` and there was a typo.

You can use a `LEFT JOIN`. For example:

```
select
  d.data1,
  d.data2,
  case when s.tournament_id is null then 'false' else 'true' end
from tournaments_data d
left join tournaments_subscriptions s
   on s.tournament_id = d.tournament_id
  and s.account_id = d.account_id
  and s.account_id = 1 -- specific account
```

Result:

```
data1   data2   case w...
------  ------  ---------
data1a  data2a  true
data1b  data2b  false
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/azZXVggYDvCRXL4LRm4Qvm/0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LEFT JOIN. SQL is below:

```
SELECT TD.*, CASE WHEN TS.tournament_id IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS flag
FROM tournaments_data AS TD
LEFT JOIN tournaments_subscriptions AS TS 
ON TS.tournament_id = TD.tournament_id AND TS.accound_id = TD.accound_id
```

DB FIDDLE LINK: [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a067ab9b651cda382da880858cd69322)